# NSArray from one view controller become NULL when using at viewWillApper method of another view controller?

Tags: null, nsarray, viewwillappear

i have a problem while calling NSArray from another view controller, solution may be simple but as a beginner i am confused.

here is my problem,

i am tryiin to send an array from my firstViewController to SecondViewController and i need to update the array value in to my UILabel which is on SecondViewController.

```
secondViewController.m

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil  andStationName:(NSArray *)stationName;
// stationName is from firstViewController
    {

// now the stationName have the array values


   NSArray *stationNames=[[stationName mutableCopy]retain];

 //take a copy to stationNames

 }
```

now i need to update this value to my UILabel

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
 {
//stationNameDisplay is a uilabel

 stationNameDisplay.text=[stationNames objectAtIndex:0];
  NSLog(@"station name %@",[stationNames objectAtIndex:0]);

 }
```

but [stationNames objectAtIndex:0] only shows null value, i don't know why?

Comment: U can try Sreeram's answer that  time u will get array in secondViewController

Comment: i already got the values in init of second view controller, but the problem is i can't update that value to my uilabel, at viewWillApper

Comment: the proble is  that viewWillAppear  not being called inside a UINavigationController

Comment: please check this link http://www.touchthatfruit.com/viewwillappear-and-viewdidappear-not-being-ca

Comment: bu i am not navigating from firstViewController to SecondViewController. just am initiating only to send the array through init

Comment: but viewDiLoad only calls once, i got the array value on init and copies to a string stationNames=[stationName description]; but in viewWillApper if i print the value of stationNames , it shows null. –

Comment: I added a link to similar question, please see for better understanding

Comment: I have edited my answer and try it out and let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't try to send values through `- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil` method or a `viewDidLoad` because in a tabbar the users will switch between views without unloading the view or reinitializing the view controller.

Declare a variable in the Application `appdelegate.h` as follows

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject{
 NSMutableArray *stationnamespassed;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *stationnamespassed;
@end
```

In `appdelegate.m`

```
@implementation AppDelegate
@synthesize stationnamespassed;

 -(void) dealloc{
          [stationnamespassed release];
          [super release];
         }
@end
```

In `firstviewcontroller.h` declare this

```
@interface firstviewcontroller {
  NSMutableArray *stationnamestobepassed;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *stationnamestobepassed;
@end
```

In `firstviewcontroller.m` declare this

```
@implementation firstviewcontroller
@synthesize stationnamestobepassed;

-(void) someaction{
   stationnamestobepassed = [NSMutableArray     
     arrayWithObjects:@"string1",@"string2",@"string3"];
    AppDelegate *appDelegate=[[UIApplication sharedApplicaton] delegate];
    appDelegate.stationnamespassed = self.stationnamestobepassed;
}

-(void) dealloc{
  [stationnamestobepassed release];
  [super release];
 }
@end
```

In `secondviewcontroller.m` access app delegate variable as follows

```
@implementation secondviewcontroller

   -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
 {
//stationNameDisplay is a uilabel
AppDelegate *appDelegate=[[UIApplication sharedApplicaton] delegate];
 stationNameDisplay.text=[appDelegate.stationnamespassed objectAtIndex:0];
  NSLog(@"station name %@",[appDelegate.stationnamespassed objectAtIndex:0]);

 }
-(void) dealloc{
      [super release];
     }
@end
```

Try this way.For more info on different ways of persisting data across different view controllers, Read [this](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2009/05/the-death-of-global-variables/) article.

Comment: as u said i have tried @property (nonatomic,retain) NSArray *stationNames;  copied the array value to stationNames, but i can't access stationNames on viewWillAppear , or can't print on uilabel

Comment: As MUSTHAFA said try assigning your label value in `viewDidLoad` method and let me know

Comment: but viewDiLoad only calls once, i got the array value on init and copies to a string stationNames=[stationName description];   but in viewWillApper if i print the value of stationNames , it shows null.

Comment: the problem is am using tab bar, both view controllers are in tab bar, and i am not pushing the view.

Comment: If you are using storyboard use prepareForSegue method to pass values from one viewcontroller to other

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the scope of your NSArray you are taking from the init constructor is wrong. You need to create a property for your stationNames array, and set it like this:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNibNil andStationName:(NSArray *)stationName;
// stationName is from firstViewController
 {   
     self.stationNames = stationName;
 }
```

You can then access it like this:

```
 stationNameDisplay.text = [self.stationNames objectAtIndex:0];
 NSLog(@"station name %@",[self.stationNames objectAtIndex:0]);
```

Comment: as u said i have tried @property (nonatomic,retain) NSArray *stationNames;  copied the array value to stationNames, but i can't access stationNames on viewWillAppear , or can't print on uilabel

Comment: Ok so from your above examples, I assume youre still passing the array in via an overriden initWithNibName method. Try, in your firstViewController, setting the array like @Sreeram said.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to retain each elements in array stationName, for NSArray contains only references of them and mutableCopy doesn't retain them automatically in the copied NSArray.

Comment: Create an secondViewController Instance inside FisrtViewController, alloc stationNames  and assign values in side FirstViewController. that time u will get array in secondViewController

Comment: try this:     for (NSUInteger i=0; i<[stationName count]; i++) {
        NSObject *obj = [stationName objectAtIndex:i];
        [obj retain];
    }

Comment: no need to retain any object, yes if you can ensure the elements have not been released while viewWillAppear is executed.

Comment: An array retains its objects itself. And be careful with retaining an array mutable copy, as copying gives you not autoreleased object (just like alloc), so I think you may have a memory leak there.

Answer (score 0):

firstViewController.m

```
-(void)someMethod
{

    NSArray *stationName=[[NSArray alloc ]initWithObjects:@"One",@"Two",@"Three", nil];
    secongViewController *sView=[[secongViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"secongViewController" bundle:nil];
    sView.stationNames=[[[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:stationName]autorelease];

    [self.view addSubview:sView.view];
}

@interface secongViewController : UIViewController {

    NSArray *stationNames;
}

@property(nonatomic,retain) NSArray *stationNames;
@end


@interface secongViewController : UIViewController {

    NSArray *stationNames;

    UILabel *labe;

}

@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UILabel *labe;
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSArray *stationNames;
@end

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"station name %@",[stationNames objectAtIndex:0]);
    [labe setText:[stationNames objectAtIndex:0]];

}
```

If u trying  updating label text  inside viewWillAppear: u will not , because at the time viewDidLoad IBOutlet(UIController memory)  loaded to view.

Comment: U can print inside viewWillAppear: but its not updating UIcontroller value